# LinqToSql DataContext cache and memory usage

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-sql, caching, datacontext

I was wondering if the LINQ to SQL `DataContext` cache use [`WeakReference`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.weakreference.aspx) or a similar system to avoid using too much memory after a few requests?

Does this behavior depends on the `ObjectTrackingEnabled` property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No; it uses regular references, because normally it needs to keep hold of the objects to perform change tracking (as you mention), but also for the identity manager to work.

This, however, is not a problem - because you are only meant to use a `DataContext` instance briefly, as a unit of work. Because otherwise, the overhead of the change-tracker/identity-manager would soon make the data-context completely bloated and unusable (too slow).

So; just use a data-context briefly, and let the objects get collected after your operation is complete. Don't keep hold of a data-context arbitrarily.

Sometimes, you don't need a data-context at all; for read-dominated applications, there are alternative but similar query mechanisms.

Comment: Can you give an example of an alternative but similar query mechanism?

Comment: @bzlm there are, to use a term that has mixed meaning to different people, "micro ORMs", such as dapper-dot-net, PetaPoco, massive, and Simple.Data, that may be very useful. I'm involved in dapper(-dot-net), and we wrote it specifically to allow us to re-use our LINQ-to-SQL classes, but without the overheads of L2S.

Comment: Thx, I already have to use PetaPoco in side of my L2S DataContext. I'm a bit disapointed in that behavior tho, I'm aware of the unit of work pattern we are supposed to use, but given you can't share (easily) IQueryables or Entities between different instances, it gets useless in some cases (for me at least). For the IQueryable problem, I guess I'll try to replace them with Linq.Expression<> parameters.

Comment: To discuss the design decision behind this: imo the Tracked entities should not be a problem, the ChangeSet hard references looks enough to me (you don't need to keep references to unchanged non referenced entities).